# JWT token validates correctly, but fails Azure media AES with AuthorizationPolicyEvaluationFailure error

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I've setup a simple Azure function to test out Azure media services. I'm trying to protect a video I uploaded, but I can't seem to get the JWT right. Here's the simple function code.

```
    [FunctionName("Test")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20);
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("RYhzAnz....VP0uQ==")); // removed full key for brevity
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
        };

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken("http://test.net/",
            "urn:user",
            claims.AsEnumerable(),
            expires: expires.LocalDateTime,
            signingCredentials: credentials
        );

        return new OkObjectResult(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
    }
```

I've filled out the issuer/audience in the token so that it matches what is in my Azure settings.

[image]

I've even validated that token on jwt.io, and it verified correctly

[image]

But when I test it out on the Azure Media Player, the response is a 401 with a AuthorizationPolicyEvaluationFailure.

[image]

Here's the response from the Azure key delivery service

```
{
  "Error": {
    "Message": "Failed content key policy evaluation.",
    "Code": "AuthorizationPolicyEvaluationFailure"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what I was doing wrong. Problem was hidden in plain sight. Issue came down to this line of code.

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("RYhzAnz....VP0uQ==")
```

This was getting the bytes of the security key, but the security key itself is base64 encoded. I had to change it to this instead.

```
System.Convert.FromBase64String("RYhzAnz....VP0uQ==")
```

I was able to figure this out while debugging the [Azure Media Service](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-tutorials) AES example.

Comment: Could you tell me what will we do after  decode base64 primary verification key? Or what is related to the token you mention from the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to put the the content key Id in the claims. Your policy probably requests it. Here is the line to add before generating the token :

```
claims.Add(new Claim(ContentKeyPolicyTokenClaim.ContentKeyIdentifierClaim.ClaimType, keyIdentifier));
```

Comment: What is the ContentKeyIdentifierClaim used for? What would the identifier be?

Answer (score 0):

Commenting below two lines help me sort this issue....

```
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
rng.GetBytes(TokenSigningKey);
```